# Unicode length in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I have this string.

```
text = u"\ud800\udc00"
```

And when I check `len(text)`, it returns `2`.

I am not sure why does this happen.

Answer (score 3):

Because there are two unicode code points in your string, and a string is a *sequence of unicode code points* (in Python 3).

In Python 2, that isn't a string, but a `unicode` object, which again, is a sequence of unicode code points.

Comment: Python 3.3+ and wide builds of older versions allow individual surrogate codes in strings, even though it's not valid Unicode. In these cases the repr is `u'\\ud800\\udc00'`. In a narrow build the repr will be `u'\U00010000'` (without the `u` prefix in Python 3), but the length will be 2.